# Facebook AccessToken from iOS doesn't have access to email permission

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login

My app supports Facebook login and will be released to Apple Appstore real soon. I was testing the Facebook login for a while and it seemed to work all the time until now. When I login, the access token return by Facebook does not have email as one of the permission and I do need email for registering with my app. On developer.facebook.com under settings for my app, I have the following setup

```
 User & Friend Permissions: email user_about_me user_birthday
 Extended Permissions: read_friendlists
```

I also got the accessToken from my device and used https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ and pasted my access token in there but it doesn't have email as one of the scope (the only scope listed is user_friends).

The app on Facebook is set to live (non-sandbox) so everyone can access it. Also on iOS, I do not have my app listed under Settings->Privacy->Facebook even after I give my app access to Facebook by successfully signed into Facebook. When I press login with Facebook, it opens Facebook website and says the following "'My App' will receive the following info: your public profile and friend list." and it doesn't mention email in there.

I have removed Facebook app from iOS, logged out of Facebook account from iOS settings, restarted the device and also removed my app and installed again and nothing seems to be working for iOS. We do have an Android version of our app, and that is working (able to get email) without any problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Edited:

Also on Facebook it says that my app accessed email (for my profile) on Oct 25th. So it was able to access email on that day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However you are requesting the login you have to manually request the e-mail on top of basic permissions.  You do so by putting under the readPermissions an array that contains the string email, like so...

```
fbLoginView.readPermissions = @[@"email"]
```

Or in `openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler` put the first argument as `@[@"email"]`.

Weirdly, I've found that the app permissions do not often correlate the permissions that the app grabs.

Comment: Before I didn't have to do this, and without putting any permission, it works on one of the other app. But, I was able to fix it by only putting that read permission as you suggested. Thank you.